# How to prevent @media from breaking the parsing of the CSS file on some Kobo EPUB readers?

Tags: css, epub, epub3

I am working on the styling of an EPUB 3 file.

I have a CSS containing a `@media` query.

```css
@media (min-width: 460pt) {
    aside {
        float: right;
        max-width: 40%;
        margin: 10pt 0 10pt 15pt;
    }
}
```

When rendered in a browser context or Calibre, it works as expected. But on a Kobo Clara HD, this breaks the CSS file; the rules are not loaded at all.

After removing the `@media` query, the CSS file works again. So the problem is isolated to this feature.

I have tried to put the `@media` in another file and use an `@import`. Results: the main CSS is not broken anymore; but the issue is, in contexts where `@media` works, the rules are not in the right order, so the applied rule is not the one I want. Put in other terms, the `@media` rule MUST come **between** the main rules regarding the element I want to style, but because the `@import` rule MUST be defined first as per the CSS specifications, so it does not fit my requirements.

> - Well, I may theoretically deconstruct my main CSS file in 3 files (the beginning, the media, the rest), called each with an `@import`, but this seems excessive; I would need to break the main CSS file everywhere a `@media` rule has been added.
> - I cannot use `!important`, because subsequent rules in the main file reset some rules which are in the media.

Regarding `@supports`, I didn't find any `@supports` rule for checking if `@media` rules are supported. I have tried the following:

```css
@supports selector(div) {
  /* The same rules from the previously shown code block. */
}
```

It makes the main CSS file work, because `@supports selector(...)` is still experimental nowadays (Nov. 2023) and unsupported on my Kobo. But what it demonstrates: we can have a way to disable the `@media` rule block with `@supports`.

Are there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because, for Kobo ereaders, advanced CSS features are loaded for `.kepub.epub` files and not `.epub` files. The `.epub` files are rendered with a broken (or simplistic) implementation of CSS.

Simply change the extension of the file to `.kepub.epub`, and the stylesheet won't fail due to `@media`.

Don’t use *Calibre* to transfer the file; or else *Calibre* will change back the extension to `.epub`, so it’s better to copy the file directly to the storage. If you really want to use *Calibre*, install *KoboTouchExtended*, a *Calibre*'s third party extension.

After this change, other unsupported CSS features will also start working, such as `:not` and `::before` / `::after`. This will also make the footnotes preview work (as long as the implementation in the file is correct).

To distinguish between EPUB and KEPUB files loaded on a *Kobo Clara HD*, in the ebook list, you will find next to the book title the file type:

- `.epub` files are noted as “EPUB”
- `.kepub.epub` as “KOBO EPUB”.